# RV32E version of the soft-float methods such as __divdi3 and __mulsi3

Tags: c, gcc, riscv

I have managed to build an RV32E cross-compiler on my Intel Ubuntu machine by using the official riscv GitHub toolchain (github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain) with the following configuration:-

```
./configure --prefix=/home/riscv --with-arch=rv32i --with-abi=ilp32e
```

The ***ip32e*** specifies soft float for RV32E. This generates a working compiler that works fine on my simple C source code. If I disassemble the created application then it does indeed stick to the RV32E specification. It only generates assembly for my code that uses the first 16 registers.

I use static linking and it pulls in the expected set of soft float routines such as __divdi3 and __mulsi3. Unfortunately the pulled in routines use all 32 registers and not the restricted lower 16 for RV32E. Hence, not very useful!

I cannot find where this statically linked code is coming from, is it compiled from C source and therefore being compiled without the RV32E restriction? Or maybe it was written as hand coded assembly that has been written only for the full RV32I instead of RV32E? I tried to grep around the source but have had no luck finding anything like the actual code that is statically linked.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Just checked in more details and the compiler is not generating using just the first 16 registers. Turns out with a simple test routine it manages to only use the first 16 but more complex code does use others as well. Maybe RV32E is not implemented yet?

Answer (score 2):

The [`configure.ac`](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain/blob/master/configure.ac) file contains this code:

```
AS_IF([test "x$with_abi" == xdefault],
    [AS_CASE([$with_arch],
        [*rv64g* | *rv64*d*], [with_abi=lp64d],
        [*rv64*f*], [with_abi=lp64f],
        [*rv64*], [with_abi=lp64],
        [*rv32g* | *rv32*d*], [with_abi=ilp32d],
        [*rv32*f*], [with_abi=ilp32f],
        [*rv32*], [with_abi=ilp32],
        [AC_MSG_ERROR([Unknown arch])]
)])
```

Which seems to map your input of `rv32i` to the ABI `ilp32`, ignoring the `e`. So yes, it seems support for the `...e` ABIs is not fully implemented yet.

Comment: Well at least that makes sense! Thanks